# Need another database value updated when dhtmlxgrid column select option changes

Tags: php, mysql, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlxgrid to display MySQL database information to users with the ability to edit line cell data. One column `productionstage` displays as a combobox column with the ability to change the value to `Staged Done`. This updates the DB table perfectly. However, I need to check the value of the productionstage column to test for the `Staged Done` value. If productionstage is set to that value, I need another column `stagestatus` in the same table to also update it's value to `Production`. It's preferred that the stagestatus column in the DB table NOT be a end-user viewable column and instead triggered on the back end.

All help is appreciated. Thank you!

My CODE:

```
//update row
$sql =  "UPDATE invoices SET editby='".$editBy."', editpage='".$editPage."', serverip='".$serverIp."', ip='".$Ip."',floornotes='".$_GET["floornotes"]."',productionstage='".$_GET["productionstage"]."' where id=".$_GET["gr_id"]."'";
$res = mysqli_query($sql);


if (($_GET['productionstage']) == 'Staged Done' ) {
    //update stagestatus from 'Scheduled' to Production if moved to 'Staged Done' in Glass Prep.
$sql1 = "UPDATE invoices SET stagestatus = 'Production') WHERE id=".$_GET["gr_id"]."'";
$res1 = mysqli_query($sql1);

}
```

NOTE:: I understand that the existing method used by the previous programmer exposes the script to SQL Injection Attacks - I will also be updating this script to use prepared statements... Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any errors? You have an extra parentheses in `$sql1`, but it might be an typo.

Comment: I do not get any errors when inspecting the page but I do see that dhtmlxgrid fails any line update due to the second UPDATE statement. Is dhtmlxgrid only meant to handle one UPDATE statement per grid? If so, I will adjust the code to test for the value and run the correct UPDATE statement based on IF statement logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I must have just had a bug in the code somewhere. Upon some testing and editing, the following code solved the issue (and yes dhtmlxgrid can handle more than one UPDATE statement per grid).

Solution:

```
    //update row
$sql =  "UPDATE invoices SET editby='".$editBy."', editpage='".$editPage."', serverip='".$serverIp."', ip='".$Ip."',floornotes='".$_GET["floornotes"]."',productionstage='".$_GET["productionstage"]."' where id=".$_GET["gr_id"]."";
$res = mysqli_query($sql);



if (($_GET['productionstage']) == 'Staged Done' ) {


    $sql1 = "UPDATE invoices SET stagestatus = 'Production' WHERE id=".$_GET["gr_id"]."";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($sql1);

} else {

    print("<action type='error'>SQL query error</action>");

}
```

Please Note: My Next step is updating the code further using prepared statements to make the script more secure.

Thank you!